# Detecting an undeclared identifier before the compiler

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm working on a multi-platform codebase, and on one of the platforms, `sprintf_s` isn't available, but `snprintf` does exist, so in this case the solution is to have the line

```
#define sprintf_s snprintf
```

However, I'd like to either automatically revert this (or throw a compile time error so I can do it manually) should the platform implement `sprintf_s`.

I've found multiple questions here to detect if a class has a member function defined (or an overload exists of a stream operator), but none for a function like `sprintf_s`.

(I'd rather not use anything experimental, but if `std::experimental::is_detected` is the only solution so be it).

The ideal solution looks something like

```
if !sprintf exists
    #define sprintf_s snprintf
```

but something like the following would also be acceptable

```
static_assert(!sprintf_s_exists, "sprintf_s is now defined");
```

Comment: Compiler typically defines set of macros distinguishing the platform it's compiling to. You can use them with `#ifdef` and `#endif`

Comment: And if you can't find compiler macro, you will need to test feature and set macro accordingly using cmake(or whichever build system you have).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen that doesn't really solve my problem. I can already conditionally define out the function based on the platform (the entire file only exists on my target platform), but that doesn't solve the sdk changing within that platform, and I don't want to have to check it every time I do the upgrade if I can get it to tell me automatically.

Comment: I always faced this issue in last project, where OS functions will keep changing across Operating Systems. So, used to compile custom test files as cmake feature test and set macros accordingly. which made my life bit easier.

Answer (score 1):

An implementation that provides `sprintf_s()` should define the macro `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__` in `<stdio.h>`. You might also define `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` to `1` before including the header yourself.

You can also check for implementations you are sure support it, such as MSVC with a minimum version number, and enable it conditionally only for those.

The more general appriach is what auticonf traditionally did: attempt to compile a small program that calls the function you're testing for, and check the return value. If the program compiles and runs as expected, the script added a macro such as `HAS_SPRINTF_S` to the configuration file, and the program could then test for that.

Answer (score 0):

Such problem (speaking generally) is not uncommon. Many systems solve it during `configure` phase of the build (when generating platform specific `make` or `ninja` files). There you would normally provide the build system generator with a small "feature test" app which would either compile fine or fail to compile, and you can base the logic of the build system (usually by having it define required compiler macros) based on either of outcomes.

In `CMake` something similar to the above is called [cmake-compile-features](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html)